# Google chart array - Invalid row type for row 0

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

Working with the Google Charts API for the first time, and with everything I've got here I would imagine it works. But when I look at the Chrome console, I get an error saying `invalid row type for row 0`. Tried looking around for why that would happen, but I can't exactly figure it out.

If it helps, [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ca9151/google-charts-api-using-database-in-Asp-Net/) is the tutorial I was basing all of this off of.

Here's the code I have:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function drawVisualization() {
        var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(['TurbTemp_F'], ['45.68'], ['45.68'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.5'], ['45.5'], ['45.68'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['46.04'], ['46.22'], ['46.4'], ['46.58'], ['46.58'], ['46.76'], ['46.94'], ['47.12'], ['47.12'], ['47.3'], ['47.66'], ['47.66'], ['47.66'], ['47.84'], ['48.02'], ['48.02'], ['48.02'], ['48.2'], ['48.38'], ['48.74'], ['48.74'], ['48.92']);
        var options = {
            title: 'Title here',
            vAxis: { title: 'vvv' },
            seriesType: 'bars',
            series: {
                3: { type: 'area' }
            }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(gdata, options);
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot surrounding [] in gdata
Should be

```
var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['TurbTemp_F'], ['45.68'], ['45.68'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['45.5'], ['45.5'], ['45.68'], ['45.86'], ['45.86'], ['46.04'], ['46.22'], ['46.4'], ['46.58'], ['46.58'], ['46.76'], ['46.94'], ['47.12'], ['47.12'], ['47.3'], ['47.66'], ['47.66'], ['47.66'], ['47.84'], ['48.02'], ['48.02'], ['48.02'], ['48.2'], ['48.38'], ['48.74'], ['48.74'], ['48.92']]);
```

this produces another error "Not enough columns given to draw the requested chart." I add another column, then error with values as Strings, so i end up with

```
var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Day','TurbTemp_F'], ['1',45.68], ['2',45.68], ['3',45.86], ['4',45.86], ['5',45.86], ['6',45.86], ['7',45.86]]);
```